# How to create an object that is a type of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have seen in different tutorials, or examples online of different classes using a composition of multiple classes to create a more complex object. I understand most of the creation of said objects, but one part I have seen baffles me, and I'm not sure how you would describe this type of class which is why I am finding difficulty researching it online.

An example of what I'm looking for would be

```
public class House{

private Kitchen kitchen;
private LivingRoom lRoom;
private Bedrooms[] bedrooms;

public House(...){}

}
```

The part of this that I don't understand is how to create the 'Bedrooms[]' class. Like if its an array, would it just be

Bedrooms[] rooms = new Bedrooms[5];

and this array would be created inside of a Bedrooms class?
Please help shed light. If I haven't explained my confusion well enough, I can try to re-explain.

Comment: "Like if its an array, would it just be... " Yes. Although, I would suggest `Bedroom[] bedrooms` instead of `Bedrooms[] bedrooms`.

Comment: [This might help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is nearly already accomplishing your desired result. You wouldn't create a "`Bedrooms[]`" class, but you would create a `Bedroom` (singular) class to model a single bedroom, then have an array of `Bedroom` instances from that class you made. Ex)

```
Bedroom[] rooms = new Bedroom[5]; // You now have an array of 5 Bedroom objects in House.
```

Comment: That's perfectly understandable. Just an extension of my question - if my attributes for my bedroom class are say length, breadth, height, would these attributes need to be predefined when inserting my rooms object into my House object?

Comment: You could do it that way, for example pass a `Bedroom[]` array in the `House` constructor and set it that way, or derive the array as such that it makes sense for your use case elsewhere. For example `for (int i=0; i<rooms.length;i++) rooms[i] = new Bedroom(5, 10, 15);`, assuming your `Bedroom` constructor is set up to accept those values as arguments.

Comment: Thanks a great explanation and easily understood. Thanks Jamie!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already created a `House` class, you know how to create classes. (That's stated for the fact of stating the obvious, and so this isn't a 1 line answer.)

All you need to do is to create a `Bedroom` class. Java will do the rest to make it into an array. All it is is multiple instances of the `Bedroom` class, which you can put different data into, just like any other array.